# How to iron clothes at high temperature setting?

Tags: clothing, temperature, efficiency, time

I have observed if I iron clothes at higher temperature setting, it fades away the color of my clothes. But if I lower the temperature then, it doesn't iron the clothes well and it takes more time to complete the task. What should I do so that my clothes color doesn't fade away even at high temperature setting?

Comment: Iron them inside-out and use ironing-spray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprinkle some water on the clothes and iron them in a high temperature, as in this process the heat will be used for both evaporating water droplets and ironing clothes. I hope this ironing process doesn't interfere with the color of the clothes.

Answer (score 2):

From most to least important, but you should do all:

- iron inside out
- use steam function (if your iron has it)
- use proper ironing board, with metalized heat-reflective surface
- iron through a cloth (a special ironing cloth or mesh works best)
- sprinkle clothes with water

damp cloth is nice substitute for iron with steam, but it's hard to use properly as it considerably lowers the temperature at first, so you crank the iron up, and then when it dries up the cooling effect is no more, so you end up burning your clothes.

Comment: Good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will work, but I heard ironing through a damp wash cloth will help to prevent color fade.

If you are looking for creases in cloths (dress pants, etc.) then I can help you do it less often, which will also prevent color fade because you won't be doing it as often.

1. Get some soap.  Any bar soap will work, but the little hotel soaps seem to work the best.
2. Iron a crease into the garment.
3. While it is still hot, turn it inside out and run the soap down the crease.  You want to make sure that some soap stays on the clothing.
4. Turn it right side out and go over the crease again.

The soap acts like a glue and will melt into the crease.  You can often get 3 or 4 washes out of it before the soap lets go and you have to repeat the steps.

Used to use this on my BDU's. Takes a little extra time in the beginning, but you save time in the long run by not having to iron every time you do laundry.

Comment: I don't understand: why do you want to add creases (Step 2 and 4) when the whole point of ironing is to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid touching the hot surface of the iron directly with the clothes you are ironing. 
Use another cotton cloth in between. That way the color dyes won't burn off.